# Can I send transaction to a view|pure function?

Tags: solidity, web3js

This is the contract:

```
uint public result;
address public owner;

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function add(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint) {
    result = a + b;
    return result;
}
```

Normally we can use contract.add.sendTraction({...}) call the "add" function using Web3.js. However, I found that I can also use contract.add.call(), like this:

[image]

I wonder why this can be valid? All I know is that "call" cannot change the state of a contract, but I do change the state in the statement "result = a + b".

Besides, if things like above is possible, can I send transactions to "view" or "pure" functions? If possible, since functions like those won't change the state, would that require any gas?